# Where does the C standard define the else if statement?

Tags: c, if-statement, c99

I was just curious about the `else if` statement in C so I looked at the [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) standard and found nothing. Then I looked at the grammar but again no `else if`

```
selection_statement
    : IF '(' expression ')' statement
    | IF '(' expression ')' statement ELSE statement
    | SWITCH '(' expression ')' statement
    ;
```

How is the `else if` declared in C. By reading the standard, how can I notice it is part of it?

Comment: The last `statement` in `IF '(' expression ')' statement ELSE statement` can be another `if` statement.

Comment: `else if` is a byproduct of an `if` statement being a statement.

Comment: To clarify, there's nothing special about the `if` after an `else`. It's just another statement.

Comment: In C18 section 6.8.4 **Selection statements**

Comment: @WeatherVane is the C18 available for download?

Comment: Please see [Where do I find the current C or C++ standard documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/83763/)

Comment: @nowox Yes, it is. Drafts are available for free.

Comment: [C2x draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2478.pdf) in PDF format from [JTC1/SC22/WG14 - C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/)

Comment: There is no `else if`. The code `if (x) { foo(); } else if (y) { bar(); }` is missing a set of braces. The compiler sees it as `if (x) { foo(); } else { if (y) { bar90; }}`. The `else if` shorthand is allowed because the braces are optional when the `else` is followed by a single statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `else if` statement is officially defined as byproduct of the `if` statement in §6.8.4/1, C18 by declaring the syntax:

> **Syntax**
>
> 1 selection-statement:
>
> `if ( expression ) statement`
>
> `if ( expression ) statement else statement`
>
> Source: C18, §6.8.4/1

The last "*statement*" in the latter form describes that another `if` statement can be followed after an `else`.

---

Beside that, you can find an, of course non-normative, example of its use in the C standard in normative appendix G in the code example at G.5.1/8:

```
if (isnan(x) && isnan(y)) { ... }
else if ((isinf(a) ||isinf(b)) && isfinite(c) && isfinite(d)) { ... }
else if ((logbw == INFINITY) && isfinite(a) && isfinite(b)) { ... }
```

This is the only place where an `else if` statement appears as it is in the C18 standard.

So regarding:

> By reading the standard, how can I notice it is part of it?

There at least although examples are non-normative it is part of it.

Answer (score 3):

C 2018 6.8.4 says a *selection-statement* may be “`if (` *expression* `)` *statement* `else` *statement*”. C 2018 6.8 says that latter *statement* may be “*selection-statement*”, and so it may be an `if` or `if … else` statement, which results in a statement containing `else if`.

Comment: It might help to point out that this would be different in a language where subclauses of control flow constructs had to be blocks.  Nobody wants to write a long if-else chain like `if (expression) { statements; } else { if (expression2) { statements; } else { if (expression3) { statements; } else { ... } } }`.